# Forbids functions with `static_assert`

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time, static-assert, deleted-functions

I want to prevent certain functions from being called. Let's ignore the case of calling the function via a function pointer or something, and just concentrate on the case of direct function call. I can do this with `= delete`. However, the diagnostic issued is not quite informative. I considered using `static_assert`, with which you can supply a custom diagnostic message. I placed a `static_assert(false, ...)` statement within the function body, hoping that it fires when the function is called. However, it turns out that the `static_assert` fails even if the function is not called. Any suggestions?

**Additional Note:** The function is forbidden unconditionally. So, `std::enable_if` does not apply here. The motivation for such a function is that I want to prevent certain use, which would otherwise compile fine with overload resolution. So I can't just remove the function. `deprecated` is not what I want. I want a compilation error, not a warning.

Comment: Use `= delete`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) can't really stop a function from being called, it's purpose is for compile-time assertions which gives errors. You might want to look at e.g. [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead.

Comment: Why does the function exist, when it is not meant to be called? Simply remove it from your codebase.

Comment: The more I re-read your question, the more confused I get, what do you mean by "prevent certain functions from being called"? Do you want the function to not exist at all (which is what using `= delete` does, as does actually removing it)? Do you want to get a compile-time error depending on some specific condition? Do you want to get a compiler error if called using some specific arguments, or if called from only some places? Do you want to stop someone from calling the function depending on some run-time condition?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `std::enable_if` does not apply here. The function is forbidden unconditionally. If I simply remove the function, overload resolution will chose another function, which I don't want.

Comment: @cdonat The function is there so that overload resolution does not choose another one. I want to prevent certain use, which would otherwise compile fine with overload resolution.

Comment: Then `= delete` is the way I recommend. The function will still be available for overload resolution, but if selected the compiler will say that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, I guess `= delete` may be the only way. I just want to provide some custom diagnostic message to let the user know what is really going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I found a similar question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694896/generating-link-time-error-for-deprecated-functions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). If you cannot remove the function you may remove implementation which is similar to  `= delete`, but only causes link-time error. Your code will compile if nobody calls that function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with others that you shouldn't use `static_assert` for this at all and mark the function as deprecated instead.

`static_assert`ions fire at the time they are compiled. For an ordinary function, this is the time it is parsed, not the time it is called.  For a `template`, however, it is the time of instantiation. So you can make your function a `template` like this.

```
template <typename...>
struct always_false { static constexpr bool value = false; };

template <typename... Ts>
void
never_call_me(Ts&&...)
{
  static_assert(always_false<Ts...>::value,
                "You should have never called this function!");
}
```

If `typename...` is not right for you (because the function is overloaded), try narrowing it down to only match what you want to make an error.

The trick used here is that `always_false<Ts...>::value` depends on the type parameters `Ts...` so it cannot be evaluated until the `template` is instantiated. (Even though we can clearly see that it will always be `false`.)

Comment: Would `always_false<Ts...>::value` and simply `false` make a difference?

Comment: It does make a difference! I guess this would be the solution I want. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, the trick is to delay the determination of the condition until the type arguments are known. Since `false` does not depend on the parameters, it is evaluated right away. `always_false<Ts...>::value`, while – well – always false, technically still depends on `Ts...`.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a member function then `= delete` is your best (most portable) bet.  Otherwise, both GCC and MSVC have support for marking a function as "deprecated", which will cause the compiler to issue a warning when the function is called.

From [C++ mark as deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define DEPRECATED(func) func __attribute__ ((deprecated))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEPRECATED(func) __declspec(deprecated) func
#else
#pragma message("WARNING: You need to implement DEPRECATED for this compiler")
#define DEPRECATED(func) func
#endif
```

Usage:

```
DEPRECATED(void badidea(int a, const char* b));
```

.... and now with C++ 14, we can write it as:

```
#define DEPRECATED(func, reason) [[deprecated(reason)]] func
```

With usage:

```
DEPRECATED( void badidea(int a, const char* b), "This function was a bad idea");
```

Comment: Don't forget the [C++14 `deprecated` attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Comment: I hadn't.  Mainly because I didn't know it existed so that I could forget about it!

Comment: It's nice to know the `deprecated` thing. But I really need a compilation error, not a warning.

Comment: So use the appropriate compiler options to make that particular warning an error (or, like me, just use -Werror and make *all* warnings be errors).

Comment: Totally agree with `= delete`.

Answer (score 0):

As a shorter version of @5gon12eder's good answer, you can simply use

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void never_call_me(Ts&&...ts)
{
  static_assert(not (std::is_same_v<Ts,Ts> && ...),
                "You should have never called this function!");
}
```